# How can i extend downloading of personal data in ASP.NET Core Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

The default "download personal data" operation of Mvc Core creates a json with personal data like so

```
    var personalData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var personalDataProps = typeof(IdentityUser).GetProperties().Where(
                    prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PersonalDataAttribute)));
```

and serializing the personalData dictionary

```
    foreach (var p in personalDataProps)
        personalData.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(user)?.ToString() ?? "null");
```

For extending `Identity User` properties i have created a second `UserData` table with an `one to one relationship` like so

```
public class UserData
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("IdentityUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }
}
```

How can i add the properties of `UserData` to the `personalData` dictionary?

I have tried the following

```
    var userDataProps = typeof(Models.UserData).GetProperties().Where(
        prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PersonalDataAttribute)));
    foreach (var p in userDataProps)
        personalData.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(user)?.ToString() ?? "null");
```

but i get an `TargetException: Object does not match target type.` at the last line.

Comment: How did you define the `user`?This error message means that the data in `user` does not match the UserData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo here:

```
var user = new UserData()
{
    UserId = "1",
    WebSite = "website1",
    CompanyName = "company1",
    IdentityUser = new IdentityUser()
    {
        Id = "001",
        UserName = "aaa"
    }
};
var personalData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var personalDataProps = typeof(IdentityUser).GetProperties().Where(
                prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PersonalDataAttribute)));
foreach (var p in personalDataProps)
    personalData.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(user.IdentityUser)?.ToString() ?? "null");

var userDataProps = typeof(UserData).GetProperties().Where(
                prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PersonalDataAttribute)));
        
foreach (var p in userDataProps)
    personalData.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(user)?.ToString() ?? "null");
```

Result:

[image]